# Reduction of repetitive calculations in Table

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation, version-7, timing

If I generate two tables inside a function which are

```
function[n_, x_, y_]:=(
 table1 = Table[i* x/n^x, {i,1,n}];
 table2 = Table[i* y/n^y, {i,1,n}];
)
```

where `y - x = z`. So I can notice that I am making very similar evaluations and generate two almost identical tables. Can I do it faster, I mean: after generating of `table1` can I generate table2 based on values from table1? Of course I am looking for some solution which is faster than generating `table1` and `table2` as above. 
I was trying to use ParallelTable but it was wrong direction I think. I will be grateful if someone can suggest something.

Answer (score 2):

If your n is a very big integer and your x and y are real values, and you need realy high speed, than you should try `Compile`:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {n, _Integer, 1}},
     n*x/Length[n]^x, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
     Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C"
     ]
f[n_, x_, y_] := {cf[x, Range[n]], cf[y, Range[n]]}
```

For n=500000, x=1.1, y=0.9 this is more than 14 times faster than @george2079's answer on my computer.

**Edit:**
Even faster with:

```
ff[n_, x_, y_] := cf[{x, y}, Range[n]]
```

**Edit for version 7:**

```
cfNL = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {n, _Integer, 1}},
       n*x/Length[n]^x, Parallelization -> True
       ]
fNL[n_, x_, y_] := {cfNL[x, Range[n]], cfNL[y, Range[n]]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But if I can ask, can I run this code using Mathematica 7? Because I have a message "Unknown option 'RuntimeAttributes'" and I tried to import CompiledFunctionTools` but it didn't help.

Comment: @SugerBoy: The first version (before the edit) should also work after removing "RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}". I'll make an extra vesion 7 edit, but I can't test it, as I deinstalled Mma 7 long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ClearAll[f];
 f = Transpose@Table[i {##2}/#^{##2}  , {i, 1, #}] &;
 f[3, x]
 (*{{3^-x x,2 3^-x x,3^(1-x) x}} *)
 f[3, x, y, z]
 (* {{3^-x x,2 3^-x x,3^(1-x) x},
     {3^-y y,2 3^-y y,3^(1-y) y},
     {3^-z z,2 3^-z z,3^(1-z) z}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something like this:

```
       function[n_, x_, y_] := ({table1, table2} = 
         Table[i {x/n^x, y/n^y}, {i, n}] // Transpose;)
```

But note your example does not need `Table` at all:

```
       function[n_, x_, y_] := ({table1, table2} =
            {x/n^x, y/n^y} # & /@ Range[n] // Transpose;)
```

Of course assigning to global variables inside a function intended to be returned as side effects is not such a good practice so..

```
       function[n_, x_, y_] := {x/n^x, y/n^y} # & /@ Range[n] // Transpose
```

used as:

```
       {table1, table2}=function[n, x, y]
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working very nice. But if I can ask, what in the situation when 'table1 = Table[i* x/n^x, {i,1,x}];' and 'table2 = Table[i* y/n^y, {i,1,y}];'. Can I also find one universal commend?